# Textures not showing up in BGE player

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv

I'm probably doing this very wrong, but I used to just be able to map the textures with uv and everything would work in the BGE player as it did in the viewer. what is causing everything to just turn white? Thank youu

Blend file - http://www.filedropper.com/apartment_1

Comment: Did you just put the texture in the UV/Image editor or did you set up the material that uses the texture?

Comment: Sharing that file is useless. You need to pack the textures into the blend, if you want it to be portable.  Also, as @Denis said, after you UV map the image, you still need a material on the object. This way the UV maps know what images to use in the BGE.

Comment: is the object you want to texture parented to another object?
because i have a similar problem. when i un-parent my object the texture shows fine. the only problem is that i need the relationship for my scene to work.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a result by making the switch from 'GLSL' to 'Multitexture' shading.
Try switching your shading method.

[image]